# Unscriptable result of generetion function

Tags: python

I have generator function and function that works witn results of the first one. For example:

```
def gen():
    a = 2
    b = 3
    yield (a, b)

def func():
    c = gen()[0]
    d = gen()[1]
```

I have error "'gen()' is unscriptable"
How can I fix it and work with result of func?

Comment: Please post the actual error message. It's probably `TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable`, with a traceback, not `"'gen()' is unscriptable"`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here.

---

First, generator objects are not sequences, they're iterators. And you can't index an iterator the way you can a sequence, by subscripting it like `[1]`. You can loop over them with a `for` statement or a comprehension, or manually call `next` on them until they're done, but you can't `[1]` them.

That's why you get an error message that says the generator object is not subscriptable.

---

Second, you didn't want to subscript the generator anyway. Your generator yields an iterable of multiple pairs. It happens to only `yield` once, but that's no different from a sequence with just one pair in it—it's still not the same thing as a pair.

Consider the nearest sequence equivalent:

```
def seq():
    a = 2
    b = 3
    return [(a, b)]
```

Obviously `seq()[0]` is going to be the tuple `(2, 3)`, and `seq()[1]` is going to be an `IndexError`. So, even if you *could* subscript generators, your code wouldn't make sense.

---

What you actually *want* to do is either take the first pair, or loop over all the pairs (I'm not sure which). And then you can do `[0]` and `[1]` to the/each pair.

So, either this:

```
def func():
    for pair in gen():
        c = pair[0]
        d = pair[1]
```

… or this:

```
def func():
    pair = next(gen())
    c = pair[0]
    d = pair[1]
```

Or, if you really wanted to call it twice for some reason, this:

```
def func():
    for pair in gen():
        c = pair[0]
    for pair in gen():
        d = pair[1]
```

… or this:

```
def func():
    c = next(gen())[0]
    d = next(gen())pair[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is get the first and second element without `iterating` over an `iterator`. You need to `iterate` over it to get values from it like -

```
for i in gen():
    c, d = i # you need this because you are returning a tuple
```

You can go through [this](https://pymbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/igd.html) post to learn more about `iterators` and `generators`